# How can I redirect one of my pages to a random page of another website using regex options?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect a page to `example.net/path` where **path** is a random number between 1 and 5127.

E.g:
`http://www.example.com/bin` **----redirects to---->** `https://example.net/3417`

I then want to increase each redirected page number by 10 as in this example starting from a path of 1000:

`http://www.example.com/bin` **----redirects to---->** `https://example.net/1010`
`http://www.example.com/bin` **----redirects to---->** `https://example.net/1020`
`http://www.example.com/bin` **----redirects to---->** `https://example.net/1030`

etc., as I know, this can be done either with *htaccess* or with a simple *php page*.

Comment: In .htaccess context, you’re going to have trouble implementing any “counting” or “random”, so this part should rather be done by a script. You will obviously have to _store_ your current value somewhere, so that you know what you have to add 10 to the next time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not. job for .htaccess, rather for PHP if you're using that but you need some sort of state management (e.x. database) to keep track of previous redirect number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will achieve what you're after. It makes use of php sessions to keep track of the number you're redirecting to.

```php
<?php
session_start();

// Check whether you've already redirected a user and if not, create a random number between min and max
$MIN = 1;
$MAX = 5127;
$rand = $_SESSION['last_redirect'] ?? rand($MIN,$MAX);

// Check whether you're within 10 of the maximum or not and if so, generate a new random number, if not add 10 on.
$rand = ($rand <= ($MAX-10)) ? $rand+10 : rand($MIN,$MAX);

// Store the value in a session for the next time the page is loaded
$_SESSION['last_redirect'] = $rand;

// Redirect ...
$redirect_to = 'https://example.net/'.$rand;
header("refresh:0; url=$redirect_to");
?>
```

## Here's an example of it in action:

**1) Navigate to the php page:**
[image]
**2) Get redirected to example.net with a random number appended:**
[image]
**3) Navigate back to php page (step 1) and get redirected again but increased by 10:**
[image]

This will keep increasing by 10 until you clear your browsing history for the php page (or unset the session variable), or until you reach the maximum number you specified. Once you are within 10 of the maximum it'll make a new random number and redirect you to that instead.

Comment: It's working fine, but on big numbers it doesn't work. It changes numbers to ex: 8.3424234435+E20 . How can I fix it?

Comment: Your use case above says a maximum of 5127? ... https://www.google.com/amp/www.geekysolution.com/how-to-convert-scientific-notation-to-an-int-and-a-float-in-php/amp/

Comment: I didn't think there will be a problem like this. solutions on geekysolutions.com didn't solve problem.

Comment: @SteveAndersson sorry I think I've misunderstood, can you tell me exactly what the new problem is? How can I reproduce it?